# Rails 4, make attribute inaccessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

previous rails 4 I had in a model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  ...
end
```

But now `strong_parameters` replaced the `protected_attributes` so I comment it and use `permit`.

Now I discovered that I can access attribute without permitting it.

In `rails c` I manage to do this:

```
2.0.0p247 :002 >   User.new(admin: "1")
 => #<User id: nil, name: nil, email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: nil, remember_token: nil, admin: true> 

2.0.0p247 :016 >   user = User.new(name: 'Nir', email: 'nir@example.com', password: 'foobar', password_confirmation: 'foobar', admin: "1")
 => #<User id: nil, name: "Nir", email: "nir@example.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: "$2a$10$xVnY8ydd5SoaLVipK5j4Del40FrOmu4bKypGjBEwvms7...", remember_token: nil, admin: true>
```

When obviously I should not be able to set and change the admin attribute. Only `user.toggle(:admin)` should be able to.

So what am I not understanding or should do right.
And how to make this test pass:

```
  describe "accessible attributes" do
    it "should not have allow access to admin" do
      expect do
        User.new(admin: "1")
      end.to raise_error(ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent a user from setting the `admin` property, you should **not** add it as a parameter of the `permit` method.

```
params.require(:user).permit(:name, :whatever_else_you_allow)
```

Keywords in this are: `params` (it deals with parameters) and `permit` (you tell rails which properties to allow for).

`Strong Parameters` will make Action Controller parameters forbidden to be used in Active Model mass assignment until they have been whitelisted. In your test however, ***you set the property directly on the model***. Nothing prevents you from doing that.

Comment: I have and use `permit` without `admin`. Should that be enough? Is there a way to prevent setting the property directly? If so do I need to use it?